# Perl : Load modules on the fly

Tags: perl, mod-perl

All,

Can we do something like this in Perl

1. Push a Perl module on the backend
2. And the Perl based server loads the PM file on the fly

The Perl module probably has some Algo, which can be tuned or changed time to time , and the changes are seen w/o needing to restart the server.

Comment: What do you mean by Perl modules? Are you talking about the ones you use when you say `use Foo::Bar;` -- the ones most people download from CPAN? What do you mean _Push a Perl module on the backend_? You can load a Perl module _on the fly_. That is, when the script is being executed rather than at _compile time_. This is used when a module is optional, or loading the module is slow, and you don't want to do it unless you have to. What do you mean by _Algo_? The old programming language from the 1960s?

Comment: we have a Apache based server , that cooks the DIV areas which is encapsulated inside perl module.Am looking at changing these perl module to tune or code the DIV areas diffrently, and such changes are immediately visible on the browser w/o requiring to restart the apache server.

Comment: Ah! This is `mod_perl`. I changed your the tag on your question to *mod_perl*.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you're using mod_perl if you're talking about needing to restart Apache to see your changes. If that's correct, you might want to look into the [Apache2::Reload](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/Apache2/Reload.html) module. This will automatically reload modules when they are touched.

```
PerlModule Apache2::Reload
PerlInitHandler Apache2::Reload
```

Comment: Thanks Holland , do we have anything in perl that would help here,like would 'requires' help ? As we have similar requirement in other service that does'nt run in Apache.

Comment: Try the CPAN module `Module::Reload` for the same functionality outside of mod_perl.